# Generating Hibernate composite key object from hbm file

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm

(Parenthetical rant:) I'm a Hibernate beginner getting slightly frustrated by the overhead of a simple join that I could write in 15 seconds in SQL. (End rant)

The situation is thus: I have 2 tables that both contain the same composite primary key - let's call the columns in both tables 'ID' and 'Version'.  I need data about a particular ID/Version from both tables, so

```
select a.xxx, b.yyy 
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.ID = b.ID
    and a.Version = b.Version
    and .....
```

Bad table design, but not in my hands.

In Hibernate, my online research suggests creating a separate composite key class to be shared by the tables, with an A object containing a B object, and a one-to-one mapping between them in A's hbm file.

In my project, all my Hibernate data objects are generated with hbm files and located in the same place.  So I'd like to know if I can create this composite key object also using an hbm file and store it with its brethren.  The issue is, it doesn't map to any *table* in particular (or, you could say it maps to 2 tables).  I'm trying to determine if it's possible to create this composite key class with an hbm file, and also if it's advisable or not to do so.  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post an example of the table definition? do you mean that the two tables share the same key definition (i.e. both tables have a composite primary key of `id` and `version`; but that these are separate entities that just happen to have the same type of key), or that both tables refer to a 3rd table which defines this "key" entity?

Comment: I can't post my code for proprietary reasons, and writing an example will take too long.  But yes, your 1st possibility is correct - both tables happen to have composite primary keys of id/version, and I want some data from both tables, so I need to join composite PK of table A (id/version) to composite PK of table B (id/version).  I have therefore used the same composite key class as the id for both entities.  This wasn't my question above, but I am now having a great deal of difficulty getting the DAO to work, lots of "could not resolve property" errors...maybe the topic of another post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood this key object. You should write a java class, which represents this key, consisting of a id and a version in this case. Then you use this class as composite primary key type. You can't seen anything about this class in the database. It is just used by you and by hibernate, to identify an instance.

The one-to-one relation is used to synchronize primary keys. One object should reference the other, and will get its own primary key from that.

Documentation:

- [Chapter 5. Basic O/R Mapping : Mapping declaration : composite-id](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid)
- [Chapter 8. Component Mapping : Components as composite identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html#components-compositeid)

Most people who switch from SQL to Hibernate are frustrated, because they try to work with hibernate like with SQL. Then they don't benefit from it but get the additional overhead.

So here my short advise:
You should not think in tables anymore. Unless you are writing mapping files, *just forget tables*. Only think in classes, objects and object oriented structures. Don't perform queries for everything you want to "do in the database". In most transactions, you perform a single query at the beginning, then you navigate along properties, using lazy-loading (which your code doesn't recognize). The code which implements the actual logic does not know anything about a database anymore. Then it starts to be fun to work with hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I appreciate it...it seems though, that Hibernate is great when you're totally in control of a perfectly designed env, which many are not.  I've also seen the tutorial you link to, I didn't see it address this.

I don't think I misunderstood the key object, but maybe my question wasn't clear enough.  I am writing mapping files for all classes that are tied directly to DB tables.  My issue/question was that since this key class is NOT tied to any table, could/should it be generated using a hbm file, motivation being for best project organization and consistency.